# out of diskspace because of sparsebundle

Tags: disk-space, sparsebundle

My disk is out of space all of a sudden and I found out that a directory in /Users/.harith/harith.sparsebundle is using 178 gigs of space. What is this directory? How/Why is my mac using it. Is it safe if I remove the directory?

Comment: Are you using FileVault (1) on that user?

Comment: What version of the OS are you running?

Comment: Using FileVault - Yes. OS is Snow Leopard.

Comment: Have you verified that the trash has been emptied? If you add up the sizes of the folders in your home folder (Desktop, Documents, Downloads, etc.), do they add up to ~178 GB?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`/Users/.harith/harith.sparsebundle` is the encrypted contents of your home directory. When you are logged in (as user `harith`), then the *unecrypted* contents of that same directory are visible under `/Users/harith`, that is, your home directory.

So what you're seeing is, your hard disk is full. And your home directory is taking up 178 GiB of space.

**IT IS NOT SAFE TO DELETE `/Users/.harith/harith.sparsebundle`!!!!! This is your home directory's files, and deleting this will delete or corrupt your home directory!!!**

What you will want to do is look for large files within your home directory, and move those to an external drive. As @lemonginger mentioned, movies and music are good places to look, but not so they're not being decrypted as he said, that's irrelevant. And don't just move them anywhere, you need to move them to a different hard drive otherwise you won't solve the problem.

If you don't have a second hard drive, consider moving files to a cloud-based storage system, such as [Apple's iCloud service](http://www.apple.com/icloud/) or [Amazon's Cloud Drive](https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/learnmore). This can be either a permanent solution, or a temporary storage space until you can expand your local disk storage. Amazon may be a good choice because they offer 5 GB at no cost, and I believe you can get up to 20GB free if you purchase any MP3 from them.

**In order to reduce the size of your home directory's encrypted sparsebundle, you need to log out**. After you log out, if you have deleted files from within your FileVault home directory, you will see a dialog appear with a progress indicator which states "Reclaiming unused space in  home directory". What this is actually doing is removing the parts of `/Users/.harith/harith.sparsebundle` which are no longer in use (because you have deleted files).

A side note: `/Users/.harith/harith.sparsebundle` is only when you are logged in. When you log out, `/Users/.harith/harith.sparsebundle` is moved to `/Users/harith/harith.sparsebundle`, and it's moved back when you next log in.

Comment: I currently don't have an external hard drive. Will it work if I move the movies to /tmp or somewhere else for the time being?

Comment: @harithski: No. You will make the problem *worse* if you move the files to another location on your hard disk, because you'll actually be copying them, using *more* space... until you log out, when the space will be reclaimed. But in the end you'll be right where you started. Your best bet is to go buy a hard drive, or burn them to DVD.

Comment: `/tmp` is still space on your boot volume...

Comment: What you could do is place the content in [Apple's iCloud](http://www.apple.com/icloud/) or any other "cloud" based storage system (including [Amazon.com's cloud drive](https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/learnmore) which has 5GB at no cost), at least temporarily. This would free up space.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are running File Vault and that is your Home directory. A useful tip if you are using older versions of File Vault is to store a lot of your music and movies outside of your home folder, so that they aren't being encrypted and decrypted all the time. Or upgrade to lion, which handles encryption completely differently (and much better IMHO)

Comment: You are right. I have 90 gigs of music and movies. I'll try moving those outside the home directory.

Comment: @harithski: This won't save any disk space... it will just waste time, and in fact, will use *more* disk space until your home directory is compressed.